# How can double-clicking a file in explorer be hooked?

Tags: c++, windows, hook

When a user double clicks a file to start it, I need to carry out a custom action if the file meets certain criteria.

In WindowsXP, detours could be used to hook ShellExecuteEx in explorer.exe, and the file name was accessible. I need to do something similar in Windows 7 and 8.

How can I execute some code when files are double clicked, and have the name of the file available?

I need a method that will continue to work if Windows Updates patch explorer.

Comment: Only when they are double-clicked or simply when they are shell-opened? Take a look at HKCR and put your program in the appropriate verb. Also, tread lightly when doing so, or your program easily becomes a plague upon the land.

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea. There may be an appropriate way to accomplish whatever it is you want to achieve, if you can tell us what that is.

Comment: Why did Detours stop working in Windows 7?

Comment: @Deduplicator When shell opened. I want to handle all verbs for all file types.

Comment: @Cody Gray - explorer.exe doesn't call ShellExecuteExW internally anymore.

Comment: @Andrew Medico - The criteria for the file could be something like 'is it read only', the custom action could be something like  'copy the file to c:\archives'

Comment: If you can't find a user-mode solution, one alternative approach would be a file system filter driver, but that's awfully complicated and might suffer from false positives depending on your needs.

Comment: I wonder whether shortcut menu handlers are invoked when shell-opening a file, in order to determine the available verbs?

Comment: @HarryJohnston - From experimenting, it appears that shortcut-menu handlers are only invoked just before the shortcut-menu is displayed.

Comment: There was an IShellExecuteHook interface, but it's been deprecated (maybe it can still work for you): http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/861efce3-eb74-4259-b254-b79cb4daa76c probably for good reason. Otherwise, it's doubtful you'll find a similar official way.

Answer (score 8):

A brief check using `procmon` shows that every time a file is activated by explorer (by either double clicking it or by pressing enter). Explorer searches for `HKCR\*\ShellEx\DataHandler`.

`DataHandler` is one of many types of [windows shell extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144067%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

So while the documentation states that it's for drag&drop actions it seems that it always calls it when 
opening a file.

I've followed the [How to Create Data Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144163%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#implementing_data_handlers) tutorial on how to register one, just with one minor change: I've added the `DataHandler` under `HKCR\*\ShellEx\DataHandler` with a custom GUID and a corresponding `CLSID` entry and linked it to a dll that does nothing. And now it was loaded every time I've clicked or "entered" a file. I didn't go as far as implementing all the required interfaces but according to the documentation:

> The Shell initializes the handler through its IPersistFile interface.
>   It uses this interface to request the handler's class identifier
>   (CLSID) and **provides it with the file's name**.

So theoretically it should be accessible to a dll that implements the required interface, and you could just access the file name on each access execute the custom action and do nothing else.

I don't currently have the time to write such a dll myself( maybe later) but it looked like a nice direction that you can explore.

Comment: This is highly unreliable. DataHandler is an open interface usable by any program. It's called many times on many occasions by the Windows Shell itself (right clicking on the file for example to display the context meny), not only when you *execute* the underlying file. And it may get worst if custom extensions are installed in the Windows Shell (many *are*) as they may use it for other reasons.

Answer (score 4):

So basically you want to do what an antivirus does, right? intercepting all I/O calls? You want something called [`filters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn641617) (Last time I used it was on my old XP machine). Filters are the way to go if you don't want to write your own driver!

This is far better than all those nasty API hooks. [From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541610):

[image]

you see that "Minifilter A"? That's probably where you wanna hangout for the next couple of days!

Answer (score 2):

A bit out of my depth, but here goes. I read something ages ago that explorer calls `SHELL32!CExecuteApplication::Execute` each time an application is double-clicked. No real documentation about it exists though. If you trace the call, it ends up calling `CreateProcess`. I suppose you could hook that. However, `CreateProcess` would not work if the application is already running and it is a single-instance application, like MS Outlook for example. This function only gets invoked if explorer needs to create a process.

Comment: Probably not useful. Not every double-click ends up spawning a new process - 'open' actions may be handled by the system sending a message to an already-open instance of the appropriate application.

Comment: I knew it was a long shot but, since no one else said anything along those lines, I thought it might be useful to Scott in some way.

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar problem when i try to hook all the execution calls to a particular drive letter. Initially i hooked shellexecuteex with detour library. This failed in windows 7 as the explorer started using direct kernel32.dll or ntdll equivalent calls skipping the shell API layer.
Better way to handle custom handling on the application execution is by implementing a shell folder. I hide the actual drive letter by adding a registry key. Then i implemented a shell folder which displays the content of the hidden drive letter content. By this method, i was able to get better control of the items displayed in the explorer eventually capture the double click. Eventhough you need to write a significant amount of code to the make the UI identical to explorer, this is the more appropriate & proper documented approach for your requirement.